# Is it possible to use same training phrases in different intents?

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-es, chatbot, fallback

I'm creating a Chatbot using Dialogflow. I have a fallback intent which asks random questions to users.

[fallback intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssFYN.jpg)

For example,

```
Bot:"Do you like coffee?" 
User: Yes
Bot: Good, I usually prefer tea.
But  it gives the same response with a different question
Bot: "Do you like sports?"
User: Yes
Bot: I usually prefer tea.
```

I used "Fallback- follow up" in both intents, but still none of things have worked so far.

[coffee Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWwR3.jpg)

[sports Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pfLy.jpg)

Comment: Hi Burak, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you edit your question and provide some screenshots of the design of your conversation in Dialogflow? This helps us with providing you with a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same training phrase for multiple Intents... but there is a caveat. Each Intent with the same phrase must have different Input Contexts.

Although you say you used the `Fallback- follow up` Context in both of the Intents - you haven't. One is only triggered with the `RandomBotQuestions-Doyoulikedrinkingcoffee-followup` and the other with the `RandomBotQuestions-Doyoulikefootballbetterthanbasketball-followup` Context.

You haven't shown how you're setting these Contexts, but given the responses from the Fallback Intent, I take it you think they're somehow being set based on which response is sent back.

Although the responses are randomly picked, they're meant to be semantically the same, and only offer variation so the bot doesn't sound... well... robotic. There is no way to know which of the responses were picked.

If you want to know which response you send back, you should create Fulfillment that picks from a random reply and stores which reply was sent in a Context. Then, in a later Intent and its Fulfillment, you can use this information plus how the user replied to come up with a further response.